# How Can I Divide Two Field In SharePoint With Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

i want to divide 2 field in SharePoint using visual studio c#. I have the code as shown below

```
SPView vw = jobDef.View["All items"];
vW.ViewFields.Add("MinSalary");
vW.ViewFields.Add("MaxSalary");
vW.ViewFields.Add("AvgSalary");
vw.InLineEdit = "TRUE";
vw.update();


SPListItem newDef;
newDef = jobDef.Items.Add();
newDef["MinSalary"] = "40000";
newDef["MaxSalary"] = "80000";
newDef["AvgSalary"] = int.Parse("MaxSalary")/ int.Parse(MinSalary); // i dont know how what to do here
```

anyone help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you're trying to do. But you could try the following:

```
int avgSalary = Convert.ToInt32(newDef["MaxSalary"]) / Convert.ToInt32(newDef["MinSalary"]);
newDef["AvgSalary"] = avgSalary.ToString();
```

Comment: Hey Roman, thank you so much, it is working perfectly. You saved me a lot of time! thanks again.

Comment: thanks mate i did it, sorry but its my first time here. Any way thanks for suggestion